# Is there a way to change the python max path length setting after installing in Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

I'm having an anaconda installing issues with being unable to find directories, and it seems it stems from Python for Windows having a max path length setting enabled on install. Is there a way for me to disable this setting after the fact?

Thanks!

Comment: _I'm having an anaconda installing issues with being unable to find directories_ Can you expand on that?

Comment: Essentially when trying to install a package using pip in editable mode, it was saying certain files could not be found. The error stemmed from the path to get to said files being over 260 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this as an administrator.

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem /v LongPathsEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Are you aware of the incompatibility this setting may cause with older systems? I'm completely all for enabling long paths, just wanted to make sure you're aware of the side effects.

Comment: Yes! The code I'm working on is normally run on my linux machine in the office or on a cluster (linux as well), so I'm just trying to adjust to using a windows machine for the next few months.

I was reading about how this would break older Windows installs, but unix based systems should be fine, correct?

Comment: Yeah, as much as I gather there's no such limit on unix-like file systems:)

Comment: The "LongPathsEnabled" setting only applies to Windows 10, and it has no effect on applications that do not enable "longPathAware" in the application manifest. Thus older programs are not effected. Starting with 3.6, the manifest that's embedded in "python.exe" enables "longPathAware". Older versions, and in particular 2.x, will not support long paths unless you manually modify the embedded manifest.

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a non-admin?